# Advanced filter exact values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble advanced filtering a sheet using a list of userIDs grabbed from another sheet.  The code works, but a problem arises when I have 2 userIDs that start with the same characters.  For example, if one of the users in my list is mmiller2, my filter also includes mmiller21.  Is there a simple way to adapt the code below to filter exact values from the UserID list?  Thanks!

```
'   Filter data by userID
lastRow = Sheets("Users").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Data").Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
Sheets("Users").Range("A1:A" & lastRow), Unique:=False
```

**Edit with solution:**

I ended up using a "helper" column to accomplish this.  Interestingly, during testing when I manually entered values in the helper column in this format: ="=mmiller" it worked, but translating that into vba using this did not work:

```
Sheets("Users").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""="",CHAR(34),""="",RC[1],CHAR(34))"
```

When I looked at the output the cell displayed the actual formula of ="=mmiller" so I just put the =mmiller in the cell using vba and that worked.

Working code:

```
'   Add Username helper column for EXACT username filtering
Sheets("Users").Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheets("Users").Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "UserID"
lastRow = Sheets("Users").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Users").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""="",RC[1])"
```

Comment: If you want only exact matches then I think your criteria need to be like "=mmiller2" and not just "mmiller2".  Edit: to avoid issues with the "=" you will likely need to use a formula such as `="=mmiller2"`   https://superuser.com/questions/1155570/advanced-filter-exact-match

Comment: I've seen that, but is it possible to use if my CriteriaRange is a range of cells?

Comment: Tested this and it does work.  You just need your values to have a "="...

Comment: How did you accomplish this?  I tried changing the value in the field to =mmiller2 and "=mmiller2" and neither seemed to work.

Comment: Got it, for some reason the values were handled differently whether they were added manually or via vba.  Thank you.